# Where do I ask a question about iphone-gmail contacts tranfer?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

How do I transfer my contacts from iPhone to Gmail ? I am not sure which is the correct site to ask this question, because it is a non-technical question. Can anyone guide me please?

Answer (score 6):

[Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com) would be my first choice. It is our site for all things Apple.